# Should [clock] be split up into 3 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup-request

I was writing a question about how the clock changes between Linux and Windows, and noticed the [clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clock) tag. However, after looking over the questions, it seemed broad - or, at least, had multiple definitions. The tag is currently being used for:

- Timestamps
- System clock
- CPU clock speed

It could very well use with being split into more tags.

- For timestamp questions: The [timestamp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/timestamp) tag is already in use, no new tags needed but [timestamp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/timestamp) tags could (optionally) have the [clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clock) tag removed.
- For system clock questions: Keep them tagged as [clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clock) or change the tag to [computer-clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-clock).
- For CPU clock questions: Create a [cpu-clock-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu-clock-speed) tag (possible tag synonyms: [cpu-clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu-clock) and [clock-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clock-speed)) and retag the questions with it.

Since this tag is so broad, could it be split up into more specific tags?

Comment: [CPU-clock]. Oh how have times progressed. That did not use to be on the CPU back when I still needed to walk uphils both way, to school and back home. :)

Comment: I agree it's too broad.  [timestamp] has a definition that associates it with an event time.  Questions about time of day that aren't about a timestamp might be a better match with [date-time].  [computer-clock] might still be misused (like for [cpu-clock]), but I can't think of a better tag.  Other than those nits, I like it.

Comment: Additional thoughts: 1) if we have an issue with [clock] being ambiguous, we should not keep it as-is and rely on wiki excerpt guidance.  1st bullet: definitely remove redundant [clock] tags.  2nd bullet: replace it with [computer-clock].  2) [cpu-clock-speed] is too restrictive, excluding other possible questions relating to the cpu clock.  Just use [cpu-clock] for all questions pertaining to it.

Comment: Drive-by suggestion from an outsider: how about [real-time-clock] for clocks that keep human time?  [computer-clock] makes me think of CPU/memory/etc clock speeds.

Comment: "real time" has implications of RTOS that probably aren't intended. "wall-clock"? :)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom as in "the time displayed on your computer?"